# unable to convert string to integer using parseInt()

Tags: java, numberformatexception

As a beginner I know that Integer.parseInt() is used to convert strings to integers but here I tried a program but its not working

```
Public static void main(String args[])
{

    Scanner sr=new Scanner(System.in);
    String s=sr.nextLine();
    int i=Integer.parseInt(s);
    System.out.println(i);

}
```

I want to take a line as input and convert it into integers and print but while executing it show NumberFormatException

Comment: use `sr.nextInt()` instead

Comment: Public should be public try this and ask again

Comment: Whether you are trying to convert String to asc integer value?

Comment: are you trying to convert string into integer or integer stored in String s into integer? please tell me

Comment: I suspect the key word is "integer**s**". You can only parse a single integer at a time.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39850130/4723795

Answer (score 1):

### Not all strings can be converted to integers.

For example, how should `"xyz"` be converted to an integer? There's simply no way. Java notifies the programmer of such situations with an `NumberFormatExcpetion`. And we programmers should handle such exception properly.

```
try {
    Integer.parseInt(s);
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    // s cannot be converted to int, do sth.
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

`Scanner.nextInt()` will throw a different exception (`InputMismatchException`) for invalid inputs. Nothing is changed in terms of handling inputs that simply cannot be converted to int.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct and works fine.

Make sure that the number you are entering is within the limits of Integer [-2147483648,2147483647] as if the number is out of range then too it throws a NumberFormatException.

Although the preffered way to do this is to use sr.nextInt();

But what you have done also works just make sure that the number you are entering is actually int.

Answer (score 0):

Use try and catch block .If you are giving string in place of integer , it will print "Please enter a number not string.Code is given below

```
Public static void main(String args[])
{

    Scanner sr=new Scanner(System.in);
    String s=sr.nextLine();
    try{
    int i=Integer.parseInt(s);
    }catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println(Please enter a number not string );
    }

}
```

Comment: Ketan I am trying to print a value stored in the string for example i will take string STACK OVERFLOW as in put and I want to print the integers values stored in the string

Answer (score 0):

- You are using a line of numbers which may contain space(449 003), so
  it may result in exception.
- So you can remove the white spaces before parsing it to an integer.
- As @luke lee mentioned alphabets and special characters can not
  converted to integers, so use try catch blocks to handle those
  exceptions.

  ```
  try{
          Scanner sr=new Scanner(System.in);
          String s=sr.nextLine().replaceAll("\\s+", "");
          int i=Integer.parseInt(s);
          System.out.println(i);
      }catch (NumberFormatException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
  ```

Answer (score -1):

You should use  `sr.nextInt()`. And if you are planning on looping the entier thing, you should use `sr.nextLine()` right after `sr.nextInt()`. Otherwise the enter key you press will be taken as input resulting in unpredictable outputs.

Answer (score -1):

**1.Convert using Integer.parseInt()**

Syntax

```
public static int parseInt(String s) throws NumberFormatException
```

The parameter s will be converted to a primitive int value. Note that the method will throw a NumberFormatException if the parameter is not a valid int.

**Example**

```
String numberAsString = "1234";
int number = Integer.parseInt(numberAsString);
System.out.println("The number is: " + number);
```

**2.Convert using Integer.valueOf()**

**Example**

```
String numberAsString = "1234";
Integer intObject = new Integer(numberAsString);
int number = intObject.intValue();
```

you can shorten to:

```
String numberAsString = "1234";
int number = new Integer(numberAsString).intValue();
```

or just:

```
int number = new Integer("1234").intValue();
```