# converting a string to an integer returns a nullPointerException

Tags: java

I am trying to convert a string to an integer but in case it's not possible.

I want that integer variable to have a `null` value but I keep on getting a null pointer exception when the string is unconvertable while I need it in such case to catch the exception and handle it the way i want which is to put `null` in the integer variable.

This is my code:

```
String numt=request.getParameter("telephoneClient");
Integer tel;
try{
    tel=Integer.parseInt(numt);
} catch(NullPointerException ex1)
{
    tel=null;
} catch (NumberFormatException ex2) 
{
    tel=null;
} catch(Exception ex)
{
    tel=null;
}
```

Comment: Because telephoneClient is null

Comment: @BasilBattikhi how can `"telephoneClient"` be `null`.

Comment: numt is, though

Comment: Your servlet couldn't handle the that parameter so your front end is not sending it properly

Comment: Post your stack trace and point out the exact line throwing NPE. Without that it would just be guesswork.

Comment: Guess: `request` is `null`. Or `tel` will be converted to an `int`. Or... `getParameter(String)` throws a `NullPointerException`. - Stacktrace or it didn't happen.

Comment: i don t think so because i ve tried it with a float and it functions well

Answer (score -1):

For more information on errors from INteger.parseInt check out this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40035040/unable-to-convert-string-to-integer-using-parseint?rq=1). To get around a NPE You can do a null check on `numt` before attempting to parse to `Integer`.

```
String numt=request.getParameter("telephoneClient");
Integer tel;
if(null ==numt){
  tel = numt;
  return tel;
}
else{
    try{
        tel=Integer.parseInt(numt);
    } catch(NullPointerException ex1)
    {
        tel=null;
    } catch (NumberFormatException ex2) 
    {
        tel=null;
    } catch(Exception ex)
    {
        tel=null;
    }
}
```

Added A null check before your try block. if null, tel = null, and return

Comment: where is the more information ?
and this is will not even compile

Comment: Click the link for your first question? Will the questions code compile?