# UnparseableNumberException while parsing the FR currency

Tags: java, numberformatexception, nsnumberformatter

I keep getting an `UnparseableNumberException` while parsing the FR currency.

My code:

```
Locale locale = new Locale("fr", "FR");
NumberFormat numberFormat = NumberFormat
                .getCurrencyInstance(locale);
try {
    Number number = numberFormat.parse("€ 314,00");
    System.out.println("sadsadsadsad"+number.doubleValue());
} catch (ParseException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

Console output:

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable number: "€ 314,00"
    at java.text.NumberFormat.parse(Unknown Source)
    at PS6.main(PS6.java:26)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NumberFormatException and how can I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39849984/what-is-a-numberformatexception-and-how-can-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 3):

In France, which is using euro as currency, prices are formatted with the currency symbol at the end, with a space before it; not at the beginning. As such, `"€ 314,00"` is invalid input because the `"€"` symbol is misplaced, and you should have `"314,00 €"` instead.

```
NumberFormat numberFormat = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.FRANCE);
Number number = numberFormat.parse("314,00 €");
System.out.println(number);
```

Also, instead of creating a new locale, you can use the built-in [`Locale.FRANCE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#FRANCE).

Note that this isn't true for all countries using the euro; for example, Ireland places the euro sign before the number, without space (and with a dot instead of a comma as decimal separator). So for the locale `new Locale("en", "IE")`, the correct format would be `"€314.00"`...