# Constructing an object from a string

Tags: java

Is it possible to construct an object given a string, toString() method, and the Class itself.

For example we have class Book.

```
class Book
{
   // ...

   String getTitle()
   {
      return title;
   }

   String getPubYear()
   {
      return pubYear;
   }

   void setTitle(String _title)
   {
      title = _title;
   }

   void setPubYear(String _pubYear)
   {
      pubYear = _pubYear;
   }

   public String toString(){
      return title+" "+pubYear;

   }
}
```

If we have the String:

```
"ExampleTitle 2017"
```

How can we create an instance of the class Book, with which has attribute:

```
title=ExampleTitle

pubyear=2017
```

We can do the following:

```
Book book = new Book();
String exampleString = "ExampleTitle 2017";
String[] parts = exampleString.split();
book.setTitle(parts[0]);
book.setPubYear(parts[1]);
```

But this is long winded. Is there a more automatic way to do this?

Comment: Why do you think it's long winded? I don't know how you'd expect an "automatic" solution to have any understand of what part of your string maps to what

Comment: toString() is not meant to provide somethig parseable, and allowing recreating the object. If you want that, then use an XML or JSON marshaller/unmarshaller. Not toString().

Comment: Add a new constructor: `public Book(String title, String year) {...}`. I am not that sure if `String` is suited for `year`.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a new constructor:

```
public Book(String s) {
    String[] parts = s.split(" ");
    if (parts.length() == 1) {
        this.title = s;
    } else {
       this.title=parts[0];
       this.pubYear(Integer.parseInt(parts[1]));
    }
}
```

You should add NumberFormatException handling on your own but I recommend my [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39850130/4723795) about it.

The above constructor will take a `String`, split it by a space and perform what you have done. You can use it like:

```
Book book = new Book("Example_title 2001");
```

but it's not the best approach. You should rather use standard patterns and first extract the values you want to set to your `Book` and then pass them to the constructor.

The good way of doing what you want will be to make another constructor:

```
public class Book {

    public Book(String s, int y) {
        this.title = s;
        this.year = y;
    }
}
```

Please change `year` field to `int` or `long`. Year shouldn't be a `String` as long as you're not using `Roman numbers`.