# Java - Convert int number

Tags: java, int, double, numberformatexception

What I want to do :

I made a BMI calculator (Formula=(KG*KG)/M)
The input takes eg 186 but i get an error when inserting 1.86 (For height in metres)

`java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1.86"`

Here is my code :

```
    if (txtHeight.getText().length() > 0 && txtWeight.getText().length() > 0){
        height = Integer.parseInt(txtHeight.getText());
        heightsqr = (int) Math.pow(height, 2);
        mass = Integer.parseInt(txtWeight.getText());
        bmi = (heightsqr/ mass);
        lblBmi.setText("Current BMI : " + Integer.toString(bmi));
        }
        else{
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Please enter your weight in KG and your Height in M");
        }
```

It's a pretty basic error that I just cant seem to fix

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NumberFormatException and how can I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39849984/what-is-a-numberformatexception-and-how-can-i-fix-it)

Comment: use double instead of int

Comment: I think you need a basic understanding about datatypes in java. Look what an Integer could store and what alternatives you have.

Comment: Instead of `Integer.parseInt` use `Double.parseDouble` you have the decimal values in `string` not the integers.

Comment: Did my answer help you? If you need some clarification, please ask in a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the `stacktrace` says, you can't convert `1.86` to `int`. Why? because it's a `double`.

try:

```
mass = Double.parseDouble(txtWeight.getText());
```

In Java, we have types. `int` can only store integer. Real numbers can be stored in `float`s and `double`s but remember, that **you can lose precision**.

I don't know your whole code, so I can't tell you, what is the type of `mass`. In case you have the following somewhere in your code:

```
int mass;
```

change it to:

```
double mass;
```

*Some random thoughts:*
As you have already seen, there is a possibility that the `Exception` will be thrown. It happens depending on user input I believe. In Java we have a mechanism to secure. It's a `try-catch` block. It can be used for example in the following way:

```
try {
    mass = Double.parseDouble("1,86");
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    //somehow notify user that he has mistaken and work it out according to your business logic.
}
```

I strongly recommend reading **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39850130/4723795) tutorial** which I have provided on `StackOverflow` question `What is a NumberFormatException and how can I fix it`.

Comment: Thanks, I thought i had to retrieve the user input and format it, its actually simple.  Thank you!!

Comment: @JacquesNaudé if it's helpful, please mark it as a solution by clicking on a gray tick below the answer score.

Comment: thanks again. Also; shouldve been  *bmi = (mass/heightsqr); *
instead of *bmi = (heightsqr/ mass); *

Answer (score 0):

an `Integer` is a non-decimal value, hence 1.86 is invalid.

Try converting it into a `Double`: 
`Double.parseDouble(txtHeight.getText());`

Answer (score -1):

you try to convert a double into an int. thats causing the error. if you want to fix it, you should either only accept integers or only doubles. otherwise you will need 2 if-statements. converting to double looks like this: `height = Double.parseDouble(txtHeight.getText());`