# Java Implementation of Symbolic Aggregate Approximation - JMotif/SAX

Tags: java, time-series, sax, numberformatexception

I am executing the java version of Symbolic Aggregate Approximation technique which I downloaded from Github.

When I execute the same using command prompt as given in section 2.0 it's working well'

But when I change the parameters, like adding `-a`, `-w`, `-p`:

`E:\Paper3>java -jar "jmotif-sax-1.1.2-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar" -a 8 -d temp.csv -o out.txt -t 1 -w 28 -p 8`

it results in the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "-t"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Unknown Source)
    at net.seninp.jmotif.sax.SAXCLIConverter.main(SAXCLIConverter.java:89)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NumberFormatException and how can I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39849984/what-is-a-numberformatexception-and-how-can-i-fix-it)

Comment: This will not solve your problem with that library. But if you want an alternative implementation, you can try the Java implementation of SAX provided in the SPMF data mining library: http://www.philippe-fournier-viger.com/spmf/  (I am the founder, by the way).

Comment: accidentally bumped in here, will look into this issue, seems like some CLI parameters logic went wrong -- would be better if you have created a ticket on Github right away...

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a bug.  If there are more than 6 parameters passed to the command, it [expects the 7th element to be an Integer](https://github.com/jMotif/SAX/blob/master/src/main/java/net/seninp/jmotif/sax/SAXCLIConverter.java#L88), representing the number of threads:

```
    if (args.length > 6) {
      threadsNum = Integer.valueOf(args[6]);
    }
```

I'd suggest opening a ticket with that project.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, forgot to update the CLI parameters treatment logic for threads number. Fixed as per [last commit](https://github.com/jMotif/SAX/commit/120ee1ca0c6e5fefcd6a94a4fb31bf0a02d6fbe9). Thanks for the bug report.