# Integer.parseInt() crashes Java program

Tags: java, exception, numberformatexception

I am trying to use `Integer.parseInt()` to convert a `String` into an `int`, and if that doesn't work, `catch` the `NumberFormatException` that the program returns and reprompt the user.

However, when I enter a non-`String` value, instead of reprompting me, the program freezes.

Here is my code snippet:

```
    keepLooping = true;
    while(keepLooping) {
      String unconvertedString = "";
      int convertedInt = 0;
      try {
        System.out.print("Enter a string to be parsed into an integer: ");
        unconvertedString = userInput.next();
        convertedInt = Integer.parseInt(unconvertedString);
        keepLooping = false;
      }
      catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        userInput.next();
      }
    }
```

Comment: So it works correctly when you provide an int? What exactly is userInput?

Comment: What do you think `next()` does?

Comment: What is `userInput`? and what does `userInput.next()` do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NumberFormatException and how can I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39849984/what-is-a-numberformatexception-and-how-can-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get rid of the userInput.next() in the catch clause.

```
catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    //userInput.next();
}
```

Just let it continue the loop if exception occurs.