# Appending two decimal number strings and parse as double

Tags: java, numberformatexception

I want to get the result `0.054563` from a `String` and parse it as a `double`. My current attempt looks like,

```
String number1 = "54,563";
String number2 = "54,563";

String value = "0.0" + number1;
String value2 = "0.0" + number2;

Double rd1 = Double.parseDouble(value.replaceAll(",","."));
Double rd3 = Double.parseDouble(value2.replaceAll(",","."));
System.out.println(rd1);
```

However, when I run it, I get the following error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: multiple points

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Do you just want to parse a number and then divide by `1e6`?  Why are you performing numeric manipulations using strings? That's never going to work out well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NumberFormatException and how can I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39849984/what-is-a-numberformatexception-and-how-can-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a *regular expression* to remove all non-digits. The pattern `\D` matches non-digits. Using a `Pattern` is faster if you need to do this multiple times. So you could do something like,

```
String number1 = "54,563";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\D");
Matcher m = p.matcher(number1);
String number2 = "0.0" + m.replaceAll("");
System.out.println(Double.parseDouble(number2));
```

**or** if you only need to do it once, you could do it inline like

```
String number1 = "54,563";
String number2 = "0.0" + number1.replaceAll("\\D", "");
System.out.println(Double.parseDouble(number2));
```

Both of which output your desired

> 0.054563

Answer (score 4):

You get the exception, because `value` would be "0.054,563" and only one period is allowed in a `double` literal like `0.1`. Your code `value.replaceAll(",",".")` just changes the value to `0.054.563`, which is still illegal because of the two periods. Remove the comma before like

```
String value = "0.0" + number1.replaceAll(",", "");
```

Then, you can use `Double rd1 = Double.parseDouble(value)` without the additional `replaceAll(...)`.

I further strongly recommend you to do the conversion mathematically and not through `String` conversions and parsing, since these are unnecessary and rather costly operations.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, it's possible.  You gotta first change number1 to a string then do that + thing.

```
 String value = "0.0" + Integer.toString(number1);
```

Comment: both are strings the number1 is a string already im making it a double here Double rd1 = Double.parseDouble(value.replaceAll(",","."));

Comment: Oh, I understand now.

Comment: The obvious thing is, why don't you just make 54563 an integer and then divide by 1000000?

Comment: thank you that will work :D my math is not that good :/ and the number was a string from the start because it grabbed from selenium web scraping but ur right just make it a double :)

Comment: Ah, hehe.  yeah, double, not integer