# Why does my try-catch when used to catch an error print out the error and my catch block?

Tags: java, try-catch

I am currently learning about try-catch blocks of code and I am writing a piece of code that takes an input from a user and checks if its a integer or not. my code is

```
int classSize = 0;
boolean error = false;
    do {
        try{
            System.out.println("Hello! Please enter how many Students you have in your class: ");
            classSize = in.nextInt();
            error = false;
        }
        catch(InputMismatchException e){
            System.out.println("Invalid input. please make sure you enter numbers ONLY! No symbols or letters.");
            classSize = in.nextInt();
            error = true;
        }
    }while(error);
```

When I try to test it by entering letters I get both the error message and the try block message.

```
Hello! Please enter how many Students you have in your class: 
asdfsda

Invalid input. please make sure you enter numbers ONLY! No symbols or 
letters.

Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:939)
at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1594)
at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2258)
at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2212)
at ExcerciseOne.main(ExcerciseOne.java:65)
```

Why is it showing the catch block and the error message? Am I using the try-catch block properly?

Comment: Look at the line where the exception is thrown. I bet it's not in the `try` block but in the `catch` block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `in.nextInt()` invocation inside the `catch` block reads the bad stream left behind by the first invocation of `in.nextInt()` in the `try` block.

What you can do is to remove the `.nextInt()` calls in the `catch` block:

```
boolean hasError = true;
while (hasError) {
    try {
        System.out.println("Hello! Please enter how many Students you have in your class: ");
        classSize = in.nextInt();
        hasError = false;
    } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
        System.out.println("Invalid input. please make sure you enter numbers ONLY! No symbols or letters.");
        // variable has error remains true
    }
}
```

Or better:

Since `InputMismatchException` is a subclass of `RuntimeException`, the kind of error that throws this error can be filtered out by `if` statements. Since you only need a proper integer as an input, you can validate the input using a regular expression.

```
boolean hasError = true;
String integerRegex = "[\\d]+"; // it means 1-to-many digits
while (hasError) {
    System.out.println("Hello! Please enter how many Students you have in your class: ");
    String input = in.nextLine();
    if (input.matches(integerRegex)) {
        classSize = Integer.parseInt(input);
        hasError = false;
    } else {
        System.out.println("Invalid input. please make sure you enter numbers ONLY! No symbols or letters.");
        // variable hasError remains true
    }
}
```

Comment: Good related [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41197789/5221346) on different types of exceptions.

Answer (score 3):

You are catching the exception thrown in the `try` clause, but you are then reading from the scanner inside the `catch` again and thus throwing another exception, this time uncaught.

```
classSize = in.nextInt();
```

exists in both clauses, throwing an exception both times, but only gets caught when thrown from inside the `try` clause.

Comment: Okay. I see the problem, but how would it be fixed? I basically want the user when the catch block is used to re-enter a number. Do I have to do a try-catch within a try-catch?

Comment: That's what the loop is for, right? If they fail, it will loop back to the `try` clause. I see no reason to ask for input during the `catch` clause.

Answer (score 1):

Gendarme's answer is clear, and I add a correct demo for you:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      int studentsCount = 0;
      boolean hasError;
      do {
        try {
          System.out.println("Hello! Please enter how many Students you have in your class: ");
          Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
          studentsCount = in.nextInt();
          hasError = false;
        } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
          System.out.println("--> Invalid input. please make sure you enter numbers ONLY! No symbols or letters.");
          hasError = true;
        }
      } while (hasError);
      System.out.println("There are " + studentsCount + " students in your class.");
  }
```