# NumberFormatException when multiplying two integers

Tags: java, numberformatexception

Am trying to code a Java calculator. Am running into some NumberFormat exceptions when trying to compute the following:

```
99.9(4x/8+k)
```

The funny thing is that its giving me the error after I distribute 99.9 only if the product of 99.9 and "k" is greater than or equal to 1000. So, for values greater than 10. In my code I try to load a string variable with the sums of all the constants of an equation, it is then that the error occurs.
Here's what the code looks like:

```
double constantSum = 0;
//create a stringtokenizer object and convert each token to a double as  
//follows, then, add the double to constantSum
constantSum = constantSum + Double.valueOf(token);//the token comes 
//from the stringtokenizer object
```

The input that Double.valueOf(token) receives is 1098.900 which is 
the product of 99.9 and 11, notice that the input has been rounded to the 
thousandths place by a NumberFormat object I initialized in the code.

any ideas on how to get rid of this NumberFormat exception

Here are the details of how the exception looks like:
**Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1,098.900"
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:2043)
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)**

thanks

Comment: You're wrong, the input is not `1098.900`, it is `1,098.900`. See error message. Why would you even have that intermediate value as a string in your code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NumberFormatException and how can I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39849984/what-is-a-numberformatexception-and-how-can-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 2):

The exception is probably being caused by the comma which is inside the `token` string.  For a quick fix, you can try stripping away all commas:

```
constantSum += Double.valueOf(token.replaceAll(",", ""));
                                               ^^^^ this removes all commas
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant have the comma in the string you want to turn into a double. Remove the comma and it should work.