# How do I convert string arrays to int array?

Tags: java, arrays, numberformatexception

I get `NumberFormatException`, how do I convert `String[]` to `int[]`? The input value I get is of type 'text' for age, I have five input fields for same age input. So im using array to get five age.

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    try {

        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
        String[] name=request.getParameterValues("name");
        String[] relation=request.getParameterValues("relation");
        String[] age=request.getParameterValues("age");
        String[] occupation=request.getParameterValues("occupation");
        String[] education=request.getParameterValues("education");

        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sportsevent", "root", "root");

        PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement("insert into multiple(name, relationship, age, occupation, education) values(?,?,?,?,?)");
        for (int i = 0; i < name.length; i++) {
            if(name[i] != null) {
            ps.setString(1, name[i]);
            ps.setString(2, relation[i]);
            ps.setInt(3, age[i]);
            ps.setString(4, occupation[i]);
            ps.setString(5, education[i]);
            }
        }
        ps.executeUpdate();

    }catch (Exception e){System.out.println(e);}
}
```

Comment: Add the stacktrace please. Looks like in some  cases the Age is empty, so you have to check it before converting

Comment: The code shown above will not throw a NumberFormatException for the simple reason that it won't compile, `age` is `String[]`, so `age[i]` is `String`, and `PreparedStatement#setInt` will not accept `String` as its second parameter.

Comment: This question is, basically, "How do I parse a number?"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NumberFormatException and how can I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39849984/what-is-a-numberformatexception-and-how-can-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 1):

Try in this way;

```
ps.setInt(3, Integer.parseInt(age[i]));
```

Comment: I don get the exception now, but the data is not setting into database.

Comment: You age column data type in database is integer, right?

Comment: yes it is int, but non of the data is getting added.

Comment: And data is not being inserted in the whole row or only in that column?

Comment: the whole row is not getting generated.

Comment: Can you just try **ps.setString(3,age[i])**;