# java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string:"=3" in mongodb java?

Tags: java, mongodb, numberformatexception

filterConditions is {ID>=3,amount<400}

```
 String[] fCondition = filterConditions.split(",");
        if(fCondition[i].contains(">=")){
            int indx1= fCondition[i].indexOf("=");
            int indx2= fCondition[i].indexOf("=");
            String f1 = fCondition[i].substring(0, indx1);
            String f2 = fCondition[i].substring(indx2);
            fieldList.add(Filters.gte(f1, Integer.valueOf(f2)));
            continue;
        }
```

Comment: Show the filtercondition value and sample document.

Comment: filterConditions value is "ID>=3,amount>300" @notionquest

Comment: When you are getting the substring value for f2, please use indx2 + 1. This should get you only 3 without the equalto.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NumberFormatException and how can I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39849984/what-is-a-numberformatexception-and-how-can-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the `f2` assignment to `indx2+1` to get the value `3`. Currently, the substring gets the value from "=3".

```
String f2 = fCondition[i].substring(indx2+1);
```

**Index of:-**

Count starts from 1.

> Returns the index within this string of the first occurrence of the
>   specified character. If a character with value ch occurs in the
>   character sequence represented by this String object, then the index
>   (in Unicode code units) of the first such occurrence is returned.

The below **indexOf** returns `4`.

```
int indx2= fCondition[i].indexOf("=");
```

Substring starts from 0. When you get 4 for the substring, it gets the value from `=`. So, it has to be changed to `index+1`.

```
int indx2= fCondition[i].indexOf("=");
```