# Need to solve this Rate with FloatingDecimal

Tags: java

I try to display the content of csv file into different textboxes but it keeps on saying

java.lang.NumberFormatException:
For input string: "Rate" (in sun.misc.FloatingDecimal)

Do anyone have any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NumberFormatException and how can I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39849984/what-is-a-numberformatexception-and-how-can-i-fix-it)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what the contents are for Rate. Try using double instead of Float to store and display rate.

Comment: Im using double

Comment: Actually when i store the rate into the csv file i need to convert it to string. Then when i want to get the value i have to make it as double

Comment: Oh maybe its accessing it as a string.
Try the function Double.parseDouble(your_input)

Comment: It will not accept it because the csv file can only store String right?