# number format exception when extracting an integer from SQLITE database table

Tags: java, android-sqlite

I've looked at similar questions but non had the same issue I'm having.
My application keeps crashing on addQuestion() method and for the life of me I couldn't pin point down the problem. The error log shows number format exception at line 176 `int difficulty = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(2));`
I reviewed my code very carefully for possible SQL syntax errors but couldn't find anything.
Here's my addQuestion method

```
public void addQuestion(Question question, String question_type){

   SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();

    String query = "SELECT body FROM questions where body = '" +question.getBody()+"'";
    Cursor cr = db.rawQuery(query, null);

    if(cr.getCount() > 0){
        db.close();
        return;
    }
    else {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(type, question_type);
        cv.put(body, question.getBody());
        cv.put(answer, question.getAnswer());
        cv.put(difficulty, question.getDifficulty());

        try {
            db.insert(questions_table, null, cv);
        } catch (SQLiteException e) {
            e.getMessage();
        }
    }
    db.close();
}
```

and here's my getQuestion by type method:

```
public Question getQuestionByType(String type){
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    String query = "SELECT " + body + "," + answer + "," + difficulty + " FROM " + questions_table + " WHERE "
          +  this.type + " ='" + type+"';";

    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    String body = cursor.getString(0);
    String answer = cursor.getString(1);
    int difficulty = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(2));
    db.close();

    return new Question(type, body, answer, difficulty);
}
```

Here's the log output

```
   java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
                                                                  at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:483)
                                                                  at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:556)
                                                                  at com.maz.quizzdat.DbHandler.getQuestionByType(DbHandler.java:176)
                                                                  at com.maz.quizzdat.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:47)
```

Any help is appreciated.

Edit:
for those of you who may run into a similar situation, you cannot use `Integer.parseInt();` in this particular situation on a string, even though the string is in fact a number. Use `curser.getInt()` instead of `Integer.parseInt(curser.getString())`

Comment: What is the data type of difficulty in your db?

Comment: As your log show it may be the `difficulty` in your db are null

Comment: It says the data in that column is `null`. Are you sure your query matches any data in the third column? Are `body` and `answer` non-null?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NumberFormatException and how can I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39849984/what-is-a-numberformatexception-and-how-can-i-fix-it)

Comment: Yes. The right way to do it was to use curser.getInt(2); since, clever me, i'm getting an int not a string.

Comment: Just a tip going forward, your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. Please investigate using prepared statements and you'll be better for it.

Comment: Thanks @Jason. This is my first app using SQL (First app in general) I will definitely look into it once the basic functionalities are done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try cursor.getInt(2) instead of getString(2), since that column contains Integers?

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#getInt(int)

Edit: parseInt() obviously is not necessary anymore then.

Comment: Author added log output after I made my answer!

Comment: @MZ4Code ah, I figured the method just read the integer as a String, but oddly it just returns null if its not a string-type

Comment: @River yea me too. I'll play around with it and see why I was getting such a "strange" error. So the question is. Had I had my difficulty column to be char rather that int, would I have been able to user Integer.parseInt()?

Comment: @River no, I still got the same numberformat error after trying to parse the result to an int

Comment: @MZ4Code the answer is [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#getString(int)). *The result and whether this method throws an exception when the column type is __not a string type__ is implementation-defined.*

Answer (score 0):

You should use `if(cursor .getCount() > 0)` before `cursor.moveToFirst()` in your `getQuestionByType` method to be sure that the query has a result, then you can use `cursor.getInt(0)`

Comment: This is only a check to make sure the question does not already exist in the table.

Comment: This should be a comment about good practices, it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: See his reputation? He's not yet able to comment