# java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "1"

Tags: java, android, exception, numberformatexception

I have a big `String` to be converted into `Stop` objects, but every time I use this function returns a `java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "1"`
I don't understand why `"1"` is not a valid `String` to be converted in `Int`...

Where am I wrong?

```
private static List<List<String>> rawToList(String string) {
    List<List<String>> result = new ArrayList<>();

    for (String row : Arrays.asList(string.split("\n")))
        result.add(Arrays.asList(row.split(",")));

    result.remove(0);

    return result;
}

private static List<Stop> rawToStops(String string) {
    List<Stop> stops = new ArrayList<>();

    for (List<String> entity : rawToList(string))
        stops.add(new Stop(
                entity.get(0),
                entity.get(1),
                entity.get(2),
                entity.get(3),
                Double.parseDouble(entity.get(4)),
                Double.parseDouble(entity.get(5)),
                Integer.parseInt(entity.get(6)),
                Integer.parseInt(entity.get(7))));

    return stops;
}
```

The big `String` is quite long. I read it from [this](http://www.filedropper.com/stops) txt file.

Comment: Show up the input string and also how `rawToList` is implemented. Help us help you...

Comment: That String contains more than just that 1, so how about using a debugger to check what that String really contains?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NumberFormatException and how can I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39849984/what-is-a-numberformatexception-and-how-can-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved

I have to remove non-printable unicode characters with this:

```
string.replaceAll("\\p{C}", "");
```

Comment: Just check it answer

Comment: I can't accept my own answer in 2 days
_stackoverflow rules_

Comment: Super just check it when time allows ;)