# Assit with FATAL EXCEPTION IN MAIN in android studio

Tags: android, debugging, crash

I am new to android programming and am trying to the program to run but the problem is that the app builds and runs successfully but crashes whenever I press the GO button. My professor gave me this to accomplish as something to get started with android programming as he thought it would be challenging task that will be motivational and interesting. I looked everywhere for the solution but could not find it. My professor himself is unable to debug the code and hence.

The code is as given below:

```
**CODE 1**  

package com.example.thispc.myapplication;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.EditText;

import java.util.Scanner;

import edu.princeton.cs.algs4.EdgeWeightedDigraph;
import edu.princeton.cs.algs4.DirectedEdge;
import edu.princeton.cs.algs4.BellmanFordSP;

public class Arbitrage extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_arbitrage);

    Button Check_Arbitrage = findViewById(R.id.Check_Arbitrage);
    Check_Arbitrage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            EditText inputcurrencynumber;
            EditText inputdata;
            TextView outputarbitrage;
            inputcurrencynumber = findViewById(R.id.GetNoCurrencies);
            inputdata = findViewById(R.id.currency_table_input);
            outputarbitrage = findViewById(R.id.result);

            inputcurrencynumber = findViewById(R.id.GetNoCurrencies);
            int V;
            V = Integer.parseInt(inputcurrencynumber.getText().toString());
            outputarbitrage = findViewById(R.id.result);



            double rate,stake;

            inputdata = findViewById(R.id.currency_table_input);

            EdgeWeightedDigraph G = new EdgeWeightedDigraph(V);
            outputarbitrage.setText("Hello World");

            String [] name = new String[V];
            // The error occures here when i try to take an input
            for (int v = 0; v < V ; v++)
            {`enter code here`
                name[v] = inputdata.getText().toString();
                for (int w = 0; w < V ; w++)
                {
                    rate = Double.parseDouble(inputdata.getText().toString());
                    DirectedEdge e = new DirectedEdge(v, w, -Math.log(rate));
                    G.addEdge(e);

                }
           }

            BellmanFordSP spt = new BellmanFordSP(G,0);


            if (spt.hasNegativeCycle())
            {
                stake = 1000;
                for (DirectedEdge e : spt.negativeCycle())
                {
                    //outputarbitrage.setText((Double.toString(stake) + name[e.from()]) + "  " + (Double.toString(stake) + name[e.to()]) + "\n");


                    outputarbitrage.setText("%10.5f %s " + stake + name[e.from()]);
                    stake = stake * Math.exp(-e.weight());
                    outputarbitrage.setText("= %10.5f %s\n" + stake + name[e.to()]);
                }
            }

            else
            {
                outputarbitrage.setText("No Arbitrage Opportunity Found");
            }
        }
    });

}
}
```

Note : This code works perfectly in java IDE (I use netbeans) but crashes in android studio.

======================================================================================================================================================
**EDIT 1**

Added the log as below :

```
com.example.thispc.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                            Process: com.example.thispc.myapplication, PID: 4876
                                                                            java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "USD 1 1.6 4
                                                                            CAD 2.3 1 1.3
                                                                            CHF 4 8 1"
                                                                                at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:2043)
                                                                                at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)
                                                                                at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:539)
                                                                                at com.example.thispc.myapplication.Arbitrage$1.onClick(Arbitrage.java:57)
                                                                                at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6294)
                                                                                at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24770)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

======================================================================================================================================================
**EDIT 2**

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MuPPY.png)

Comment: Use LogCat to examine the Java stack trace associated with the crash: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Comment: update the post and added the log. I get the NumberFormatException but dont know how to fix it. help please

Comment: Um, well, your input is not a number. You cannot parse it as a number. You will need to write code that parses this whitespace-delimited set of text.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NumberFormatException and how can I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39849984/what-is-a-numberformatexception-and-how-can-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

Its getting crash because of the below line

```
rate = Double.parseDouble(inputdata.getText().toString());
```

You are trying to parse the string and parseDoubel() expects the string value which only holds numeric value, but in your case `inputdata.getText().toString()` contains character other than numbers.

Try extracting digits form the `inputdata` before passing to `parseDouble()` method

```
str.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");
```

Comment: I know its a pain in the ass but since i am new i dont exactly understand what you mean. I understand your explanation perfectly but not the suggested code snippet. Perhaps if you could edit the line

    `rate = Double.parseDouble(inputdata.getText().toString());` with the code you meant. That would be really helpful for a noob like me.

Thanks

Comment: rate = Double.parseDouble(inputdata.getText().toString().replaceAll("[^0-9]", ""));

Comment: ok so did that and it worked but now i get weird output. picture attached in the post

Comment: I also tried to solve the problem by creating a separte textbox that will only take numbers and nothing else but still get the same error even for all numbers