# number format exception when trying to parse a string

Tags: java, string-conversion

I want to convert `Integer.MAX_VALUE` to binary and want the represenation to be of type `int`. I passed it to `Integer.tobinarystring()` and wraped that with `Integer.parseint` but i get numberformatexception.

Here is the code

```
System.out.println(
    Integer.parseInt(
            Integer.toBinaryString(Integer.MAX_VALUE)
    )
);
```

Here is the exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1111111111111111111111111111111"
```

Comment: Please share the code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NumberFormatException and how can I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39849984/what-is-a-numberformatexception-and-how-can-i-fix-it)

Comment: Exactly what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Integer.MAX_VALUE` is 2,147,483,647

In binary this is:
`1111111111111111111111111111111`

If we treat that like an integer again, which is `1,111,111,111,111,111,111,111,111,111,111` you can probably see that it is much larger than the max value.

You probably want to look into `BigInteger` if you really need to deal with that as a int.

Comment: Ok that make sense thank alot! I will look into it but do you know why i have not gotten the "literal out of range" error since this is the case?

Comment: I actually want to print groups of 8 bits and want it to be int so i can format it with decimalformat rather than having to do a for loop for a string

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get the integer value of the binary string

```
1111111111111111111111111111111
```

you must use another signature of `parseInt()` that takes as 2nd parameter the `radix`, 
in this case of a binary string the radix is `2`

```
String str = Integer.toBinaryString(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
int number = Integer.parseInt(str, 2);
System.out.println(number);
```

it will print:

```
2147483647
```