# NumberFormatException for input type String : SpringBoot Restcontroller

Tags: spring-boot, java-8, spring-restcontroller, numberformatexception

I have a springboot application, with rest services. One of my services accepts, an object as a parameter with @requestBoday annotation. Previously one of my class variable was `Long` type, Which is now converted to `String`. For Example:
Previous class:

```
Class SomeObject{
   String  id;
   Long code;
}
```

Which I have converted to:

```
Class SomeObject{
    String id;
    String code;
}
```

Now when I am passing Numeric value like "4568" or similar it works fine.
but when I pass "ABC100" it throws Number format exception.

```
[ERROR] 2019-05-13 11:10:17,031 com.wallet.config.AOPConfiguration afterExceptionOfService - execution of execution(Map com.wallet.service.MemberService.redeemVoucher(String,ReferalVoucherRedeem))--------java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "SB100"
[ERROR] 2019-05-13 11:10:17,031 com.wallet.config.AOPConfiguration afterException - execution of execution(ResponseEntity com.wallet.controller.PosIntegrationController.redeemVoucher(ReferalVoucherRedeem,ServletRequest))--------java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "SB100"
```

Can anyone tell how I can fix this ? This problem occurs at following line:

```
public ResponseEntity<Map> redeemVoucher(@RequestBody SomeObject someObject,ServletRequest req) {}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NumberFormatException and how can I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39849984/what-is-a-numberformatexception-and-how-can-i-fix-it)

Comment: @Jens I don't think so. Because it is not a usual exception where you should be passing Numeric data and here on string it is throwing that exception.

Comment: @JayeshChoudhary problem is not with the code you submitted here... I think you try to parse variable `code`  to Numeric then you should take care of what value `code` variable have...

Comment: @vikrantKashyap Please check my comment on your ans.

Comment: The facts as presented here can't be the case - as you've identified, a `NumberFormatException` would only ever apply the other way around. Are you completely sure that you're interpreting the stack trace correctly? It's unlikely that it's really caused by the line `public ResponseEntity<Map> redeemVoucher...` as you say, because that's a method declaration. If that's the line number given in the exception, then I think the code you're running is out of date with what you're seeing in your IDE. Maybe try including the full stack trace in your question for more help.

Comment: @DaveyDaveDave I appreciate that you looked into this. The spring version used over here is: `1.5.4`. Also I have updated the stack trace.

Comment: That's not a stack trace, that's just the exception message. Somewhere in your logs I'd expect to see a full stack trace, which will start with "java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "SB100"", followed by several lines, each starting with "at...", showing the route through the code which led to the exception. You might need to adjust your logging config if you can't currently see it.

Comment: An alternative, if you can't get a stack trace would be to use a debugger, with a breakpoint set at the start of your `redeemVoucher` method.

Comment: @DaveyDaveDave thanks for your comment I was able to figure out the issue.