# Error message when trying to run a program

Tags: java

When I try  to run this code below and I enter any number I get this error 
 - Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""

How can this be resolved?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NumberFormatException and how can I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39849984/what-is-a-numberformatexception-and-how-can-i-fix-it)

Comment: you can write sum = sum + currentNumber; statement like this sum += currentNumber; just  advice, not related with your question's answer

Comment: post your code here

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
int n = scanner.nextInt();
```

instead of

```
int n = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());
```

Answer (score 0):

@develo is partially right by suggesting the use of `scanner.nextInt()` though if you do that you will also need to remove the calls to `Integer.parseInt` (`.nextInt()` will return an `int`, so no need to parse it into an `Integer`)

However, the core problem with your code is the loop. You loop starts from 0 and you are looping 1 too many times like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++ ) {
```

Change it to either `for (int i = 0; i < n; i++ ) {` or `for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++ ) {` and it will work fine.

Is this a college or university task by any chance? :) (my son is doing a CS degree and this type of code looks familiar :) )

Also, java convention is that classnames always start with a capital letter - so your classname should be `SumOfNumbers` with a filename of `SumOfNumbers.java`

Comment: Thanks. I tried both options and still gives this error. Yes, university task :)
Thank you for the correction!