# Getting error: Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""

Tags: android, android-studio, textwatcher

I have two `EditText` from which I am getting `Integer` values of 'quantity' and 'rate' and then I am setting this `Integer` value to `TextView` names 'Amount'.

```
    private MilkViewModel milkViewModel;
    private DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog;
    private Button dateButton,submit;
    private EditText dateText;
    private MaterialDatePicker materialDatePicker;
    private Spinner shift_spinner;
    private ImageView imageView;
   public RadioGroup rg;

    private EditText fat;
    private EditText snf;
    public EditText rate;
    public EditText qty;
    private TextView amount;

    private RadioButton rb;
    private String getDate,getShift,getType;
    private int getSnf=0;
    private int getRate;
    private int getQty;


 
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        dateText=findViewById(R.id.date_picker_et);
        shift_spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.shift_spinner);
        rg=(RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);

        snf=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.snf);
        rate=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.rate);
        fat=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.fat);
        amount= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.amount);
        final TextView amount = findViewById(R.id.amount);

        qty=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.qty);
        submit=(Button)findViewById(R.id.submit);


       // int getAmount = Integer.parseInt(amount.getText().toString());
        int getRate=Integer.parseInt(rate.getText().toString());
        int getQty=Integer.parseInt(qty.getText().toString());


        rate.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                amount.setText(Integer.toString(getRate*getQty));
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ""+amount, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

I am using `TextWatcher` on rate whenever the user enter the rate the value will be set to the `TextView` Amount. But I am getting `NumberFormatException` for input string: "".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NumberFormatException and how can I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39849984/what-is-a-numberformatexception-and-how-can-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not checking the `String` if it is empty or not before using it. Since you are beginner I will try to keep it simple for you. Just keep in mind that you need to check for not empty `String` then you can use it for other purpose.

```
rate.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        String tempRate = rate.getText().toString();
        String tempQty = qty.getText().toString();

        if (tempRate != null && !tempRate.isEmpty() && !tempRate.equals("null") && tempQty != null && !tempQty.isEmpty() && !tempQty.equals("null")) {
            int getRate=Integer.parseInt(rate.getText().toString());
            int getQty=Integer.parseInt(qty.getText().toString());
        }
        amount.setText(Integer.toString(getRate*getQty));
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ""+amount, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

Comment: Then mark it as correct answer. It will help me. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
   int getRate=Integer.parseInt(rate.getText().toString());
   int getQty=Integer.parseInt(rate.getText().toString());
```

The ***getRate*** and ***getQty*** variables above will be null since edit text will be empty as this code is executed right before the user enters the value.

**Solution:**

- From the function, ***afterTextChanged(Editable s)*** get the values dynamically from the user through edit text using the code below.

```
   s.getText().toString()
```

- Add isempty() function to check if the edit text is empty to avoid the null exception.