# Exception while executing in Scala-Spark - java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "volume"

Tags: scala, apache-spark, numberformatexception

I got an exception while executing the below code snippet.
The dataset i was working with is "stocks.csv" and
which has the columns - date, symbol, volume, open, close, high, low and adjclose

```
    val stock = 
    sc.textFile("C:/Users/kondr/Desktop/stocks/stocks.csv")
    val splits = stock.map(record => record.split(","))
    val symvol = splits.map(arr => (arr(1),arr(2).toInt))
    val maxvol = symvol.reduceByKey((vol1,vol2) => 
    Math.max(vol1,vol2),1)
    maxvol.collect().foreach(println)
```

**Error Message**

21/05/05 14:09:31 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 2)
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "volume"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)

Comment: Can you share your sample data? It looks like you have header in the csv file. why not read it directly as dataframe as ` val df = spark.read.csv("parh")`

Comment: Hi @koiralo, Thanks a ton for your response. Here is the sample data.

Comment: date symbol volume open close high low adjclose
18-04-2019 A 2874100 75.73000336 76.16999817 76.54000092 75.30999756 76.16999817
17-04-2019 A 4472000 78.15000153 75.43000031 78.31999969 74.45999908 75.43000031
16-04-2019 A 3441500 80.81999969 77.55000305 80.95999908 77.19000244 77.55000305
15-04-2019 A 1627300 81 80.40000153 81.12999725 79.91000366 80.40000153
12-04-2019 A 1249300 81.43000031 80.98000336 82.05999756 80.90000153 80.98000336

Comment: Hi @koiralo, I had tried with the .txt file format as well. here is the sample code where i have used "\t" for splitting.

Comment: In the first row you have string as `date symbol volume open close high low adjclose ` which cannot be cast to integer

Comment: val stock = sc.textFile("C:/Users/kondr/Desktop/stocks.txt")
val splits = stock.map(record => record.split("\t"))
val symvol = splits.map(arr => (arr(1),arr(2).toInt))
val maxvol = symvol.reduceByKey((vol1,vol2) => Math.max(vol1,vol2),1)
maxvol.collect().foreach(println)

Comment: okay, how do i fix this @koiralo

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NumberFormatException and how can I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39849984/what-is-a-numberformatexception-and-how-can-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you can skip the first row

```
stock.zipWithIndex().filter(_._2 != 0)
  .map(_._1)
  .map(record => record.split(" "))
  .map(arr => (arr(1),arr(2).toInt))
  .reduceByKey((vol1,vol2) => Math.max(vol1,vol2),1)
```

Or you can directly read it to dataframe as below

```
val csvDF = spark.read
  .option("header", true)
  .option("delimiter", " ")
  .csv("stock.txt")

csvDF.show(false)
```

Output:

```
+----------+------+-------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|date      |symbol|volume |open       |close      |high       |low        |adjclose   |
+----------+------+-------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|18-04-2019|A     |2874100|75.73000336|76.16999817|76.54000092|75.30999756|76.16999817|
|17-04-2019|A     |4472000|78.15000153|75.43000031|78.31999969|74.45999908|75.43000031|
|16-04-2019|A     |3441500|80.81999969|77.55000305|80.95999908|77.19000244|77.55000305|
|15-04-2019|A     |1627300|81         |80.40000153|81.12999725|79.91000366|80.40000153|
|12-04-2019|A     |1249300|81.43000031|80.98000336|82.05999756|80.90000153|80.98000336|
+----------+------+-------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

Comment: Hi @koiralo, the above solution works fine. But, I'm new to this ndlearning Spark currently and  i really want to see the DAG, on how does spark works internally when we apply transformations like map... etc. Hence i started using sc.textFile() and then transform the RDD into map transformations twice before invoking collect action. Is there a way to work on it using Spark-Core instead of DF.

Comment: Hi @koiralo,
I've tried the following code by modifying the code which you suggested. It works fine. But it is returning only one symbol along with it's maximum volume. Could you please be so kind to help.

        val stock = 
         sc.textFile("C:/Users/kondr/Desktop/stocks.csv")
        .zipWithIndex().filter(_._2 == 1).map(_._1)
        val splits = stock.map(record => record.split(","))
        val symvol = splits.map(arr => (arr(1),arr(2).toInt))
        val maxvol = symvol.reduceByKey((vol1,vol2) => 
        Math.max(vol1,vol2))
        maxvol.collect().foreach(println)

Comment: It should be like this `val stock = spark.sparkContext.textFile("C:/Users/kondr/Desktop/stocks.csv")
    .zipWithIndex().filter(_._2 == 1).map(_._1) 
  val splits = stock.map(record => record.split(",")) 
  val symvol = splits.map(arr => (arr(1),arr(2).toInt)) 
  val maxvol = symvol.reduceByKey((vol1,vol2) => Math.max(vol1,vol2))
  maxvol.collect().foreach(println)`

Comment: If the answer helped, can you mark it as an answer? And if you have any other question please another question

Comment: Hi @koiralo created a new question for the different issue. Hope that can be helpful to get the issue fixed. Thanks

Comment: @DataRealWorld take a look I have updated answer, to skip headers it should be 
`stock.zipWithIndex().filter(_._2 != 0)`

Comment: Awesome @koiralo, it's working perfectly alright. Kudosscala> maxvol.collect().foreach(println)
(EPP,5369900)
(FDEV,6200)
(MGU,67000)
(ICVT,271900)
(VNRX,394600)
(MPVD,2590200)
(GIM,717000)
(BFS,576300)
(IRT,1078800)
(SCHP,1576200)
(KONA,3411900)
(BBF,89300)