# How can I convert a string to a double using parseDouble?

Tags: java, swing, numberformatexception

```
JLabel label1 = new JLabel("Annual Rental Income");
JTextField textf1 = new JTextField("0.1",16);
//converting a string to a double cuz user input needs to be numbers
double a = Double.parseDouble(textf1.getText());
        
JLabel label2 = new JLabel("Purchased Price");
JTextField textf2 = new JTextField("1.2",16);
double b = Double.parseDouble(textf2.getText());

double result = (a / b) * 100;
```

Hi. I'm trying to run a rental yield program based on a user's input but it only calculate 0.1 and 1.2 in Jtextfield. It didn't calculate what the user add. I added 0.1 and 1.2 cuz I got "NumberFormatException" if I add words.What did I do wrong in my code. Please help.

Comment: Please edit and add a relevant title for the question. Your title does not have anything to do with the question

Comment: Also please post a [mre]. The code you posted is insufficient to compile a program that reproduces any problem you might be having

Comment: simple, don't add words. what were you trying to format to a number "0.16 examples"? -> this is a text without numerical meaning. "0.16" is.

Comment: You are converting text to a double. If the text is not a number, then you get `NumberFormatException`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NumberFormatException and how can I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39849984/what-is-a-numberformatexception-and-how-can-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 1):

you need to parse the text field values at the moment when you want to calculate the result, not when you create the text fields. This way, you'll get the updated values entered by the user.